# Get ebay item data when I click on a button from ebay api

Tags: javascript, java, php, jquery, html

Im using ebay api to get product list into my account. I get all the data and im showing it. now what I need is on a button click i need all the product data as a json so that I could store them as a record in my db. A jquery or java script solution is needed insted of a php.
My ebay script is this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var searchKey = localStorage.getItem("searchString"); 

alert(searchKey);
if(searchKey!=""){          
    $( "#loadingGif" ).empty();
    var img = $('<img id="dynamic">'); //Equivalent: $(document.createElement('img'))
    img.attr('src', '/images/rolling.gif');
    img.attr('alt','NO IMAGE')
    img.appendTo('#loadingGif');
    var val = searchKey;
    var url = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1";
    url += "?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords";
    url += "&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0";
    url += "&SECURITY-APPNAME=YOUR_APP_ID";
    url += "&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US";
    url += "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON";
    //url += "&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords";
    url += "&REST-PAYLOAD";
    url += "&keywords=" + val;
    url += "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=50";

    //Fecthing products from ebay

    $.ajax({
      url : url,
      dataType : 'jsonp',
      success : function(data) {
        items = data.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];
        var j=0;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
            var item = items[i];
            var itemId = item.itemId+"";
            var title = item.title+"";
            var pic = item.galleryURL+"";
            var viewitem = item.viewItemURL;
            var itemPrice = items[i].sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0].__value__;
            var primaryCategoryId = items[i].primaryCategory[0].categoryId;
            var primaryCategoryName = items[i].primaryCategory[0].categoryName;
            var originalPrice;
            var discountPrice = 0;
            var merchantLogo = "images/ebay.png";
            //originalPrice = parseFloat(itemPrice).toFixed(2);
            //itemPrice=((originalPrice-discountPrice).toFixed(2));
            //console.log(originalPrice);
            //++j;
            //Sdiscount=parseFloat(discountPrice+discount).toFixed(2);
            //alert(itemId);

            var prodDescUrl = "http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetSingleItem&responseencoding=JSON&appid=Labsf98a6-b419-4c0e-b20c-a3674b94530&siteid=0&version=515&ItemID="+itemId+"&IncludeSelector=TextDescription";

            $.ajax({                  
                url : prodDescUrl,
                type : "GET",
                dataType : "jsonp",                  
                contentType: "application/json",
                crossDomain: true,                  
                success : function(data) {
                  //alert(JSON.stringify(data));                      
                }, error : function (data){
                 // alert(JSON.stringify(data));                      
                }
            });              

             var oneItem = {
           PRODUCT_ID:itemId,
           NAME: title,
           DESCRIPTION:"/images/ebay.png",
           KEYWORDS:primaryCategoryName,
           PIC : pic,
           FINAL_PRICE: itemPrice,
           //ORIGINAL_PRICE:originalPrice,
           //DISCOUNT_PRICE : discountPrice
         };
         var str=oneItem.NAME+"";
         result = str.split(" ");
         console.log(result);
      $('<div class="col-sm-4">\
            <div class="product-image-wrapper">\
                <div class="single-products">\
                    <div class="productinfo text-center">\
                        <img src='+oneItem.PIC+' alt="" style="height:268px;width:249px;"/>\
                        <h2>$'+oneItem.FINAL_PRICE+'</h2>\
                        <p>'+oneItem.NAME+'</p>\
                        <a href="/addItem" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Aspitations</a>\
                    </div>\
                </div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="choose">\
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">\
                    <li><a href="/requestAspiration"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Request Aspiration</a></li>\
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>Add to compare</a></li>\
                </ul>\
            </div>\
      </div>').appendTo("#productData");
        }               
    },
    error : function(data) {
          //alert("ERROR while fetching records from BestBuy :::"+JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    }); 

//End of fetching products from ebay.           

   }  
   //setTimeout(function(){  window.location.href = "/aspirationDiscovery/"+val; }, 12000);
else{
    alert("Please search with valid details");
}
});
```

I need this thing to work on this tag in the script href="/addItem"

Comment: What is the question? What works and what does not work?

Comment: When I click a function or a href link which is appended within the above code I need all the ebay data as a Json string.

Comment: You want the data as a JSON string? That's all you want? What about the store in the DB?